# JPA Replace in database Annotation

Tags: java, jpa, replace, annotations, unique

I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "date", 
    "meterTime" }) })
public class Meter {

    public enum MeterTime {
        AFTER_FAST, AFTER_MEAL
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MeterTime meterTime;

    private Float meter;

    // constructor, getters and setters

}
```

now, when I try to insert a row with date and meterTime already existents, the row is not inserted..

but! I want to be inserted (and replace the existent row)

how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: if `date` and `meterTime` are uniquely constrained, then you will have to delete the old one and then add the new one. if you want it to be edited then you need to use entity manager's merge function

Comment: can you explain a little bit more about this merge funcion?

Comment: any decent JPA docs will explain using find() and updating the fields, or detaching objects, updating them and calling merge()